# Predict with keras triggers OOM error message

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I fit a keras model without any problem. But when I try to predict a test sample, it triggers an OOM error message:

> InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run
> _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
>
> 2022-12-15 14:52:24.087105: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)
> to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical
> operations:  AVX AVX2 To enable them in other operations, rebuild
> TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. 2022-12-15
> 14:52:26.128616: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1510] Created device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 13623 MB memory:  ->
> device: 0, name: NVIDIA RTX A5000 Laptop GPU, pci bus id:
> 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6 2022-12-15 14:52:26.711913: I
> tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of
> the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2) 2022-12-15
> 14:52:27.768758: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1760]
> TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will
> only be logged once. 2022-12-15 16:28:52.564740: W
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:457] Allocator
> (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 16.84MiB (rounded to
> 17655296)requested by op model/output/Softmax

The fact is my model's output is 137K in size (a list of products I make a softmax on). How come does it only happen during the predict phase? I tried to reduce the batch_size to 1, to no avail.

Comment: Try to save the model to file, restart the kernel, reload the model and do prediction.

Comment: I tried but it keeps failing with the same error:
softmax_op_gpu.cu.cc:224 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,137932] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc

Comment: When using tensorflow-cpu, I could execute the predict without any problem. But it makes no sense, how could the fit work on GPU then, given that it had to call predict after each epoch on the validation set?